# How to execute a Python program in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a simple Tkinter GUI, with one button and when the button is pushed I want it to run another program that I have written in Python.

```
 def openProgram ():
     #open up MyProgram.py

 MGui = Tk()
 MGui.geometry('450x450')

 mbutton = Button(text = "Go", command = openProgram).pack()
```

Seems easy enough, maybe I am not searching the correct terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use os.system:

`import os
 os.system("MyProgram.py")`

Comment: Perfect!  That's all I needed.

Comment: What if `MyProgram.py` has to be executed in a virtualenv?

Answer (score 3):

You can call functions defined in another file by `import`ing that file.

reticulator.py:

```
def main():
    print "reticulating splines..."
    #do stuff here
    print "splines reticulated"
```

gui.py:

```
from Tkinter import *
import reticulator

def openProgram():
    #call the `main` function defined in the other file
    reticulator.main()

MGui = Tk()
MGui.geometry('450x450')

mbutton = Button(text = "Go", command = openProgram).pack()
MGui.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is a much better answer than the accepted one. Calling another python program using os.system shows a lack of understanding of modular programming.

Comment: I want to open a Python program in its own window. Will this do that?